# replacing associative array indexes with their value using awk or sed

Tags: awk

I would like to replace column values of `ref` using key value pairs from `id`

`cat id`:

```
[1] a 8-23
[2] g 8-21
[3] d 8-13
```

`cat ref`:

```
a 1 2
b 3 4
c 5 3
d 1 2
e 3 1
f 1 2
g 2 3
```

**desired output**

```
8-23    1   2
b       3   4
c       5   3
8-13    1   2
e       3   1
f       1   2
8-21    2   3
```

I assume it would be best done using awk.

`cat replace.awk`

```
BEGIN { OFS="t" }

NR==FNR {
    a[$2]=$3; next
}

$1 in !{!a[@]} {

print $0
}
```

Not sure what I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1 in !{!a[@]}` is not awk syntax. You just need `$1 in a`:

```
BEGIN { OFS='\t' }

NR==FNR {
    a[$2] = $3
    next
}

{
    $1 = ($1 in a) ? a[$1] : $1
    print
}
```

- to force OFS to update, this version always assigns to `$1`
- `print` uses `$0` if unspecified

Comment: totally missed that FS problem! One question, in `$1 = ($1 in a) ? a[$1] : $1` what is the role of `?` and `:`? I assume `a` refers to the keys and a[$1] are the values?

Comment: `?:` is the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). It's like if/else except its value is an expression not a statement (and so can be used as the RHS of an assignment, where using if/else would fail).

Comment: gotcha! basically says `if $1 in a; print a[$1]; else  print $1`